# Grails 3 standalone application failed to start up due to Spring beans not being injected into BootStrap

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I can't start up the standalone application (`Application.main`). It doesn't seem to instantiate Spring beans so `BootStrap` fails.

```
import grails.util.Environment

class BootStrap {

    def dynamoDBMapper

    def init = { servletContext ->
        dynamoDBMapper.getS3ClientCache().useClient(s3Client)
    }
}
```

It worked well in 2.4.x so `dynamoDBMapper` can be autowired. Now I'm getting a null `dynamoDBMapper`. `dynamoDBMapper` is defined in `spring/resources.groovy`.

Not familiar with Spring Boot. Can you shed some lights please?

Comment: Actually, none of the beans defined in resources.groovy have been instantiated. org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext is injected into BootStrap, which doesn't seem to be aware of my application defined beans. Am I missing something?

Comment: Another update. Found the issue but pending on seeking solution. In `GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.class` @ line 146 `def beanResources = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource("classpath:spring/resources.groovy")`, it is looking for `resources.groovy`. However my IDE GGTS compiles it into class file therefore `resources.groovy` is not present. Gradle treats it well because it is recognised as "resource" file so Gradle "run" task doesn't have issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution eventually, just ask Groovy Compiler not to compile the Groovy scripts under grails-app/conf which are supposed to be resources.

[image: Project Groovy Compiler]